# CSS Overflow: Finding the scroll distance

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications

I recently added the following css styles to my web app. This prevents my webpage from having elastic scrolling, which is brilliant. I know there are many many alternative solutions, but none of them work on IOS 7. What this CSS does is allows the html page to not be scrolled, while the content inside of it can be. This prevents the user from being able to drag the page past its extents.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

However, I no longer know how to determine how far the body has been scrolled down.

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop;
document.body.scrollTop;
document.body.parentNode.scrolTop;
window.pageYOffset;
window.scrollY;
```

These all return 0. So I tried to find how far individual elements had been scrolled, and even wrapping them in divs.

```
document.getElementById("myCanvasDiv").scrollTop
document.getElementById("myCanvasDiv").offsetTop
document.getElementById("myCanvas").scrollTop
document.getElementById("myCanvas").offsetTop
```

Still returns 0. Even finding where I've clicked or touched on the screen.

```
event.changedTouches[0].pageY
event.pageY
```

All of the above return a value of 0, no matter how far the body has been scrolled.
How can I find the scroll distance?

Comment: Why do you need overflow:hidden on the HTML and not the body???

Comment: What you've done in the CSS is set it such that the html (page) doesn't scroll, and the body does. As to your question _how to determine how far the page has been scrolled down_, they page isn't currently scrolling. Take a look at this link: [determining offsets with scrolling:overflow](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/offsets_scrolling_overflow)

Comment: I agree, however I was not able to find a solution in the link you posted.

Comment: 1. You should mention that you're looking to stop the elastic scrolling in iOS 2. [There are lots of questions](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8&q=prevent%20elastic%20scrolling%20ios) dealing with the subject

Comment: Yes, there are lots of questions about it. But as of IOS 7, none of them seem to work. That is why I've come up with my own solution and the only thing I need it to know how to find how far the body has been scrolled.